# Injective choice function for infinite complete linear hypergraphs

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

A [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) $H=(V,E)$ is said to be *complete and linear* if

1. whenever $e_1\neq e_2\in E$ then $|e_1\cap e_2|=1$, and
2. for $v,w\in V$ there is $e\in E$ such that $\{v,w\}\subseteq e$.

Assuming that $V$ is infinite, is there an injective function $f:E\to V$ such that $f(e)\in e$ for all $e\in E$? (There is a Hall-marriage-theorem argument that the [answer is positive for finite $V$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374766/injective-choice-function-for-finite-fano-planes).)

Comment: If $V\in E$ then either $E=\{V\}$ or else $E=\{V,\{v\}\}$ for some $v\in V$, and the existence of an injective choice function is trivial. Suppose $V\notin E$ and $V$ is infinite. Then there is an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that $|V|=|E|=\kappa$, and there are $\kappa$ points on each line and $\kappa$ lines through each point. Then $E$ has an injective choice function, since it's a collection of $\kappa$ sets, each of cardinality $\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal.

Comment: Oops, I was wrong. Your definition allows a hypergraph with vertices $$w,v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots$$ and edges $$\{v_1,v_2, v_3,\dots\},\ \{w,v_1\},\ \{w,v_2\},\ \{w,v_3\},\dots$$ which has an injective choice function.

Comment: However, if we assume that $V\notin E$ **and** that $|e|\gt2$ for all $e\in E$, then we can prove that there is an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that $|V|=|E|=\kappa$, and $|e|=\kappa$ for all $e\in E$, and $|\{e\in E:v\in e\}|=\kappa$ f0r all $v\in V$. Unless I'm making another mistake.

Comment: I was about to write an answer, but then realized that I don't immediately see how to find the injection in the last case.  So I will post the first part of my answer as a comment here:

If you allow for edges of order 1, then then answer is no as seen by letting $E=V\cup \{V\}$.

If every edge has order at least 2 and some edge has order exactly 2, then $H$ is a "near-pencil."  In this case, you can clearly find a bijection.

So that leaves the case where every edge has order at least 3, in which case $H$ is a (non-degenerate) projective plane and thus every edge has the same order.

Comment: As bof points out, a projective plane with $|V|=\kappa$ will have $|E|=\kappa$, $|e|=\kappa$ for all $e\in E$, and $|\{e\in E: v\in e\}|=\kappa$ for all $v\in V$.  In such a case, an injection can be constructed as described here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331656/injective-choice-function-for-lines-in-an-infinite-cardinal?rq=1
However, this leads me to wonder about a more general question which I will start a new thread for in a moment.

Comment: Ok, here is a link to my more general question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375823/perfect-matchings-in-infinite-regular-bipartite-graphs

Comment: @LouisD $E=V\cup\{V\}$ doesn't satisfy the condition $|e_1\cap e_2|=1$.

Comment: @bof Of course.  Not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that.  I now see what you wrote in your first comment, so yes I believe that it does hold if some edge has order 1.

Comment: @LouisD I guess you were thinking the same as I was when I posted the same "counterexample" in a now deleted comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the discussion above, here is what I think is the cleanest proof and it has the property that $f$ is bijection (unless there is an edge of order 1).

If there is an edge of order 1, then we must have $E=\{\{v\}, V\}$ for some $v\in V$, in which case the desired injection is trivial. If there is an edge of order 2, then $H$ must be a near-pencil and $f$ can easily be found and is necessarily a bijection.

So suppose every edge has order at least 3 in which case $H$ is a non-degenerate projective plane where $\kappa:=|V|=|E|$, every edge has the same cardinality $\lambda$, and every vertex has degree $\lambda$.  Now let $B$ be a bipartite graph with parts $V$ and $E$ such that $\{v,e\}\in E(B)$ if and only if $v\in e$.  Note that $B$ is a $\lambda$-regular bipartite graph and thus has a perfect matching by [bof's answer to my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375823/perfect-matchings-in-infinite-regular-bipartite-graphs).  This perfect matching is the function $f$ you are looking for and $f$ is in fact a bijection.